# react-router, The prop `history` is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, browser-history, react-proptypes

in my React App I am using react-router-dom and in one of the components after a function is triggered I want to route to Homepage.
but I get the error

```
The prop `history` is marked as required in `GameElements`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in GameElements (created by Connect(GameElements))
```

and of course after call `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

this is my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Route component={App} />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

from homepage I got to the component like this

```
<Button color="blue" as={Link} to="/GameInit">
  START GAME
</Button>
```

now from `GameInit` I want to get back to HomePage like this

```
  cancel = () => {
    const { history, cancelGame } = this.props;
    cancelGame();
    history.push("/HomePage");
  };

GameElements.propTypes = {
  cancelGame: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
};
```

cancel game works and its reducer manipulates state as it should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap you `GameElements` is `withRouter` hoc, include it in your file

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
```

Now at the bottom, where you export your component do this.

```
export default withRouter(Connect(GameElements));
```

You can read more here in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md).

Comment: my export is by redux 'Connect(GameElements)'  it is clear in my question

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I was following this project style : https://github.com/Remchi/bookworm-react  and here I do not see exporting withRouter and that works. for instance pages/loginpage

Comment: It works there because it is a direct descendant of Router component, for a nested component inside a router component. You need to wrap it in hoc of `withRouter`